Framing scheduling problem as OR
I have N-schedules and each schedule $i$ can have $X_i$ events ($Lower_i \le X_i \le Upper_i$) within bounds for that schedule.
The schedule also has a start_time_i and end_time_i and needs to keep a gap of K-minutes between each event. Each schedule has some utility $U_i$.
For this problem, I'm splitting the time into slots (imagine 5 minutes) and each slot has a value $V_t$ and a slot cannot have more than 1 schedule.
I want to maximize sum(V_t * U_i iff event i is scheduled in slot t) for all slots $t$. How can I formulate this as an OR problem (I'm using or-tools)?
For now, my current thinking is to create binary variables for each schedule $i$ and time slot $t$ and then add constraints on them. Before I prototype it, I wanted to understand if I pick a time slot granularity that's too high if the number of constraints and variables could be intractable.

Your plan to use binary variables is reasonable. As far as intractability, it is very much an empirical question. Any solver can be overwhelmed if you have enough variables/constraints.

As you mentioned ortools, you may want to start from here:
https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling
CP-SAT supports so-called interval variables:
In particular, there are ‘optional’ intervals that include their state as a boolean argument: is_present=
This might be helpful to formulate your objective function (w/ your if-clause).
In general, if your scheduling problem is simple enough to be formulated with a limited number of time slots and with boolean vars and constraints, it should run faster than with optional interval vars.
On the other hand, along with the latter come some constraints that simplify the modeling, such as add_no_overlap
I am not aware of any easy rule of thumb just based on the granularity of your time slots.
So, referring to Prof Rubin’s answer above, the bottom line is that you need to evaluate the performance of your specific model … but you can always adjust and re-formulate it.

Have you considered using a model without a discretization, or, in other words, model your problem directly with the start (and finish) times of events? Since you are already using Google OR-Tools, you can also tap into their high-performant CP-SAT solver by modeling your problem in MiniZinc with the following blueprint:

Introduce variables $s_{i,j}$ for start times of $j$-th event of $i$-th schedule. As I understand, you choose which events to schedule; you can model that with option types for these variables. As for the lower/upper bounds on the start time, you can also encode this here with the variable range.
Model the "at most 1 schedule per slot" constraint with the disjunctive constraint over the $s_{i,j}$ variables.
Encode the maximization objective as the total utility of chosen schedules.

